# Create loop for url parameter combinations

Tags: javascript

This might be a bit of a long shot but here we go. I've got 6 different variables that I need to create different url parameters. So for example:

```
var A
var B
var C
var D
var E
var F
```

Now I need to basically account for all options between those 6. So for example for var A I'd neeed something like:

```
   if (A != '' && B == '' && C == '' && D == '' && E == '' && F == '') {
            url += A ;
         }    
else if (A != '' && B != '' && C == '' && D == '' && E == '' && F == '') {
            url += A + "+" + B;
         }
else if (A != '' && B != '' && C != '' && D == '' && E == '' && F == '') {
            url += A + "+" + B + "+" + C;
         }
```

And so on. So basically I'd need to go through all the combinations like the above example, which I'm currently doing manually and which works fine, but there must be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You could filter the items, after taking them into an array and join with `+`.

```
result = [a, b, c, d, e, f].filter(Boolean).join('+');
```